# How To Highlight The Text In PDF Files Through Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am new to programming. I am creating a Chrome extension, which is when clicked shows a pop-up with many categories with check boxes. If you click the checkbox, the extension will interact with web page and highlight text related to selected categories.

Now my question is how to highlight the text in pdf files when I am clicking the popup page checkbox. Or how to interact with the pdf files from Chrome extension. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can. The built in PDF renderer in Chrome is just a plugin. You can see that by viewing the source of the page.